# Woocommerce custom billing field (also saved, displayed in back-end and on email)

Tags: hook-woocommerce

i'm looking for the perfect all in solution. I want to add a custom billing fiels to Woocommerce based on the user ID. Also i want this field to be displayed in the back-end, saved and on the front end on the users profile, and in the mails.

*Till now with the code below it only shows the field on the fornt-end*

```
/* Debiteutnummer front-end*/
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');
function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields) {
    $fields['debiteurnummer'] = array(
        'label' => __('debiteurnummer'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('Debiteurnummer', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => true, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'text', // add field type
        'class' => array('my-css'),    // add class name
        'priority' => '150'
    );
    return $fields;
}

/* Debiteutnummer back-end*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_save_new_checkout_field' );

function custom_save_new_checkout_field( $order_id ) { 
    if ( $_POST['debiteurnummer'] ) update_post_meta( $order_id, '_debiteurnummer', esc_attr( $_POST['debiteurnummer'] ) );
}

/* Debiteutnummer on order*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_show_new_checkout_field_order', 10, 1 );

function custom_show_new_checkout_field_order( $order ) {    
   $order_id = $order->get_id();
   if ( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_debiteurnummer', true ) ) echo '<p><strong>Debiteurnummer:</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order_id, '_debiteurnummer', true ) . '</p>';
}

/* Debiteutnummer on email*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'custom_show_new_checkout_field_emails', 20, 4 );

function custom_show_new_checkout_field_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_debiteurnummer', true ) ) echo '<p><strong>License Number:</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_debiteurnummer', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Does anybody had an solution or does somebody see what i'm doing wrong?